# How to use UriBuilders correctly?

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

So, basically I want to create a REST API (jax-rs) that responds with full http-links to resources. Therefore I wanted to use a UriBuilder to build those links. I started by injecting the UriInfo object:

```
@Context
UriInfo uriInfo;
```

I've got 2 methods in my resource class:

```
@Path("/myClass")
public class MyClass {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/pathA/{id}")
    public JsonObject getA(@PathParam("id") String id) {/*...*/}

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/pathB/{id}")
    public JsonObject getB(@PathParam("id") String id) {/*...*/}
}
```

Then I tried getting an UriBuilder, for instance (I tried other ones as well) with getBaseUriBuilder and tried to create the links:

```
UriBuilder uriBuilder = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder();
String urlA = uriBuilder.path(MyClass.class, "getA").build("id-for-A").toString();
String urlB = uriBuilder.path(MyClass.class, "getB").build("id-for-B").toString();
```

The result is the following and I don't really know what's happening here, I can only guess:

```
urlA: http://myserver/myApp/rest/pathA/id-for-A
urlB: http://myserver/myApp/rest/pathA/id-for-B/pathB/id-for-B
```

urlB is clearly messed up, so what am I doing wrong here? The documentation (Javadocs or tutorials) that I found so far were not really helpful since they only explain very simple usecases, even simpler than this one. They don't explain what the different UriBuilders created by UriInfo actually do.

And maybe follow-up-question: What's the simplest way to create an UriBuilder that is cappable of creating links to different resources?

Comment: You _reuse_ the builder; it is "normal" although I can't make up the logical output of your result. You can't reuse builders, unless you have a way to "reset" them

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Just tested with using clone() on the uriBuilder. That worked. So path(..) extends the builder everytime it's called, and that's why I was getting these fishy results, makes sense :-)